# How to post a collection of models with its parent model in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, model-binding

I have a Visit model with properties and a VisitorArivalHistory Collection. I also bind this model to a form which I will show later.

```
public class Visit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpectedArrival { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpectedDeparture { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Arrival { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Departure { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public bool Announced { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VisitorArivalHistory> VisitorArivalHistories { get; set; }
}
```

The `VisitorArivalHistory` has a boolean property called `HasArrived` which I use this as a checkbox. This model basically holds one arrival history of a visitor for each visit. So a visit object knows the arrival time of each visitor.

```
public class VisitorArivalHistory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Visitor Visitor { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Arrival { get; set; }
    public bool HasArrived => Arrival != null;

    public VisitorArivalHistory() { }
}
```

I am able to bind to VisitorArivalHistory via Visit model:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h3>Arrival visitors</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Visit.Visitors.Count; i++)
        {
            var visitor = Model.Visit.Visitors.ElementAt(i);
            @if (Model.IsReceptionist)
            {
                var visitorArivalHistory = Model.VisitorArivalHistories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VisitorId == visitor.Id);
                @if (visitorArivalHistory != null)
                {
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <h5>@visitor.GetFullName()</h5>
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Visit.VisitorArivalHistories.ElementAt(i).HasArrived">Has arrived?</label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Visit.VisitorArivalHistories.ElementAt(i).HasArrived" />
                    </div>
                }
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

The `VisitorArivalHistory.HasArrived` is in the form of checkboxes I want to check or uncheck. It all works.

The problem is that I am not able to get the value from those checkboxes because when I submit the form, the `VisitorArivalHistory` is `null`.

How can I fix this? I could not find a tag helper for the checkboxes to store its values.

I am really stuck.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="HasArrived_@i" name="Visit.VisitorArivalHistories[@(i)].HasArrived" value="@visitor.HasArrived" />

Comment: It isn't working. what does [@(i)] mean exactly?

Comment: check <input type="checkbox" id="HasArrived_@i" name="Visit.VisitorArivalHistories[@(i)].HasArrived" value="@(visitor[i].HasArrived)" />

Answer (score 0):

> public DateTime? Arrival { get; set; }
>
> public bool HasArrived => Arrival != null;

Your code has set the HasArrived value to be derived from Arrival, it's no need to add a checkbox to the page.

> The problem is that I am not able to get the value from those
> checkboxes because when I submit the form, the VisitorArivalHistory is
> null.

To solve the problem, I tried the following steps to get the value of VisitorArivalHistory.

1.Add List in Visit.cs

```
 public List<VisitorArivalHistory> VisitorArivalHistories { get; set; }
```

2.Change ***VisitorArivalHistories.ElementAt(i)*** into ***VisitorArivalHistories[i]*** in your form

Result:

[image]